# Magento Frontend and admin panel logging out often

Tags: customer, login, customer-attribute, admin-login

My magento frontend and admin panel both are logging out often. 
they are not withstanding for even 10 seconds. 
Can u help to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Check these two values

System > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security > Session Lifetime (Seconds)

System->Configuration->Web->Session Cookie management

and increase these if that was low..

Answer (score 0):

in the current version 2.4 you must go to
Store-> Configuration-> Advanced-> Admin-> Security-> Admin Session Lifetime (seconds)